# Is there a way to activate a visible coordinate system on Canvas?

Tags: delphi

Is there a particular way to see the coordinates(x, y) on a TPaintBox (Canvas) in Delphi? I know that the (0; 0) point is on the left top of the canvas, but i would like to know if we can see the other numbers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, but you have to draw it manually. Or maybe it would be enough for you to write an `OnMouseMove` handler and display the coordinates under the mouse in the status bar?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using the Height and Width properties?

Comment: Do you want to see the numbers, and if so. where? In the debugger, in a label, in the caption of the form or hovering over the canvas when you are moving the mouse? Or do you mean a simple line grid with rulers, like in a graphics program (PS, Inkscape, Corel Draw, etc)?

Comment: Well anything would help. Since i've got an answer how to show it in the caption, maybe you could tell a way to make it visible like a simple line grid with rulers.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the coordinates on caption of form by this way;

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  Self.Caption := IntToStr(X) + 'x' + IntToStr(Y);
end;
```

When you leave PaintBox1 the caption will show you last cordinates.